# Google Maps simulate polyline with polygons

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, polyline

I wrote a few years ago some code that highlighted a path on a Google Map with a user typed in width. The user determines how wide the highlighted path is in meters that way they can see the ground they have covered (ex lawn fertilizing etc). I calculated the distance from a point and used the Google Maps computeOffset to determine the corners of the polygon. Next I used the bearing information from the path to plot the next polygon.

```
LatLng corner1 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(point2, widthInMeters / 2, bears + 90);
LatLng corner2 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(point2, widthInMeters / 2, bears - 90);
LatLng corner3 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(corner2, distance, bears);
LatLng corner4 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(corner1, distance, bears);

return new PolygonOptions().add(corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4);
```

I did this because at the time the Google Maps SDK had no method of varying a polyline's width to show the width of navigated path. (ex farm implement so many feet wide.) The polyline feature to this day has constant width at different zoom levels.

[image: Polygon mapping example at 50 feet wide]

The problem is as you can see bearing information is very unreliable from a device especially if it is being shaken around. The path that is created makes gaps and the polygons don't smoothly connect like a thick polyline would.

Has anyone seen any new APIs out there that have a way to highlight a path of certain width or an adjustable polyline (with spherical distance accounted for)? I thought about using smaller polygons with a higher count, but that is very resource intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a complex polygon around your oiginal path, using the corners of each retangle you already created ?

I've edited the answer, but i don't have your complete code to create the 4 corners.

You calculate a point at 90° left and distance/2, same for point on right, then you make a polygon with all thoses points (from first left to last left them last right to first right)

I've made a try and it looks not that bad... just some issues when the original path make an angle > 90° and the last point is not drawn.

[image]

```js
var debug = false ;

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var infos = [] ;
        var polyLeft = [] ;
        var polyRight = [] ;
        var strokeOpacity = 0 ;
        var widthInMeters = 20 ;
        if ( debug ) strokeOpacity = 0.6 ;

        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
          scrollwheel: false,
          zoom: 2
        });
        
        var path = [{"lat":45.878521,"lng":3.694520},{"lat":45.879269,"lng":3.693960},{"lat":45.880539,"lng":3.694340},{"lat":45.882172,"lng":3.694080},{"lat":45.883900,"lng":3.692780},{"lat":45.884430,"lng":3.692930},{"lat":45.885101,"lng":3.692600},{"lat":45.885490,"lng":3.692590},{"lat":45.887169,"lng":3.692070},{"lat":45.887421,"lng":3.691580},{"lat":45.888000,"lng":3.690050},{"lat":45.888889,"lng":3.689280},{"lat":45.889408,"lng":3.688710},{"lat":45.890331,"lng":3.688690},{"lat":45.890461,"lng":3.688480},{"lat":45.890511,"lng":3.687520},{"lat":45.891251,"lng":3.687020},{"lat":45.891769,"lng":3.686900},{"lat":45.894039,"lng":3.687510},{"lat":45.896568,"lng":3.688810},{"lat":45.897430,"lng":3.689040},{"lat":45.898140,"lng":3.688630},{"lat":45.898769,"lng":3.687980},{"lat":45.899719,"lng":3.687290},{"lat":45.900040,"lng":3.687170},{"lat":45.900101,"lng":3.686700},{"lat":45.900570,"lng":3.685970},{"lat":45.901321,"lng":3.685550},{"lat":45.902061,"lng":3.685050},{"lat":45.903030,"lng":3.683950},{"lat":45.903412,"lng":3.683880},{"lat":45.903938,"lng":3.683920},{"lat":45.905102,"lng":3.683280},{"lat":45.906361,"lng":3.682710},{"lat":45.906681,"lng":3.682380},{"lat":45.907082,"lng":3.682250},{"lat":45.907970,"lng":3.682800},{"lat":45.908772,"lng":3.682820},{"lat":45.909149,"lng":3.683270},{"lat":45.909370,"lng":3.684730},{"lat":45.909679,"lng":3.685440},{"lat":45.910191,"lng":3.685902},{"lat":45.910381,"lng":3.686270},{"lat":45.911282,"lng":3.686700},{"lat":45.912209,"lng":3.687900},{"lat":45.912281,"lng":3.688140},{"lat":45.912128,"lng":3.688280},{"lat":45.911942,"lng":3.689290},{"lat":45.911709,"lng":3.690250},{"lat":45.911339,"lng":3.691200},{"lat":45.911491,"lng":3.693050},{"lat":45.912109,"lng":3.695400},{"lat":45.913391,"lng":3.698570},{"lat":45.913940,"lng":3.700200},{"lat":45.914688,"lng":3.701790},{"lat":45.915218,"lng":3.702120},{"lat":45.916248,"lng":3.703170},{"lat":45.916889,"lng":3.703440},{"lat":45.917122,"lng":3.703860},{"lat":45.917210,"lng":3.704280},{"lat":45.917770,"lng":3.704750},{"lat":45.918739,"lng":3.704860},{"lat":45.919571,"lng":3.704730},{"lat":45.919861,"lng":3.704920},{"lat":45.920139,"lng":3.706380},{"lat":45.920460,"lng":3.706880},{"lat":45.920818,"lng":3.708750},{"lat":45.921249,"lng":3.709650},{"lat":45.921680,"lng":3.711240},{"lat":45.921822,"lng":3.712880},{"lat":45.921860,"lng":3.715220},{"lat":45.921951,"lng":3.715510},{"lat":45.922371,"lng":3.715930},{"lat":45.922691,"lng":3.718220},{"lat":45.922958,"lng":3.719330},{"lat":45.923012,"lng":3.720330},{"lat":45.922821,"lng":3.721420},{"lat":45.923988,"lng":3.718530},{"lat":45.924110,"lng":3.717490},{"lat":45.924030,"lng":3.716700},{"lat":45.924389,"lng":3.715310},{"lat":45.924671,"lng":3.714956},{"lat":45.925072,"lng":3.714200},{"lat":45.925621,"lng":3.711630},{"lat":45.926830,"lng":3.709340},{"lat":45.927231,"lng":3.709070},{"lat":45.928013,"lng":3.708873},{"lat":45.929050,"lng":3.708430},{"lat":45.929790,"lng":3.707750},{"lat":45.930168,"lng":3.707290},{"lat":45.930759,"lng":3.707410},{"lat":45.931370,"lng":3.707620},{"lat":45.931900,"lng":3.707470},{"lat":45.932739,"lng":3.706920},{"lat":45.933529,"lng":3.705940},{"lat":45.934410,"lng":3.703300},{"lat":45.934662,"lng":3.701430},{"lat":45.934841,"lng":3.699650},{"lat":45.934700,"lng":3.698620},{"lat":45.934841,"lng":3.697930},{"lat":45.935371,"lng":3.696900},{"lat":45.935741,"lng":3.696590},{"lat":45.936520,"lng":3.695530},{"lat":45.936661,"lng":3.695120},{"lat":45.936729,"lng":3.694160},{"lat":45.936600,"lng":3.693150},{"lat":45.936710,"lng":3.692080},{"lat":45.936699,"lng":3.691320},{"lat":45.936989,"lng":3.690560},{"lat":45.938160,"lng":3.689220},{"lat":45.939362,"lng":3.688750},{"lat":45.940102,"lng":3.688380},{"lat":45.940521,"lng":3.687900},{"lat":45.940731,"lng":3.687590},{"lat":45.940990,"lng":3.686870},{"lat":45.941479,"lng":3.686270},{"lat":45.941959,"lng":3.685800},{"lat":45.942169,"lng":3.685150},{"lat":45.942520,"lng":3.684640},{"lat":45.942829,"lng":3.683400},{"lat":45.943020,"lng":3.682970},{"lat":45.943199,"lng":3.682250},{"lat":45.943600,"lng":3.681720},{"lat":45.944160,"lng":3.681310},{"lat":45.944771,"lng":3.681170},{"lat":45.945690,"lng":3.681750},{"lat":45.946121,"lng":3.681730},{"lat":45.946960,"lng":3.681180},{"lat":45.947201,"lng":3.681140},{"lat":45.948021,"lng":3.681520},{"lat":45.949181,"lng":3.682410},{"lat":45.949741,"lng":3.683030},{"lat":45.949959,"lng":3.683370},{"lat":45.950809,"lng":3.684230},{"lat":45.951229,"lng":3.684470},{"lat":45.952309,"lng":3.685560},{"lat":45.953129,"lng":3.685960},{"lat":45.953758,"lng":3.686160},{"lat":45.954319,"lng":3.685820},{"lat":45.955429,"lng":3.685740},{"lat":45.956108,"lng":3.685940},{"lat":45.956200,"lng":3.686010},{"lat":45.956619,"lng":3.686740},{"lat":45.956860,"lng":3.687270},{"lat":45.956921,"lng":3.687740},{"lat":45.957260,"lng":3.688530},{"lat":45.957809,"lng":3.689250},{"lat":45.958401,"lng":3.689540},{"lat":45.958851,"lng":3.689660},{"lat":45.959599,"lng":3.690140},{"lat":45.959789,"lng":3.690520},{"lat":45.960258,"lng":3.690750},{"lat":45.960571,"lng":3.691020},{"lat":45.961521,"lng":3.692110},{"lat":45.961761,"lng":3.692530}];

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds() ;
        map.fitBounds(bounds)  ;

        for ( var i in path )
            bounds.extend(path[i]) ;

       var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: path,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        })
       poly.setMap(map) ;
       
        for ( var k in path )
        {
            var currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(path[k]) ;
            var lastLatLng = null ;
            var nextLatLng = null ;
            var headingRight, headingLeft ;
            var cas = 0 ;

            if ( typeof path[parseInt(k)-1] != 'undefined' ) lastLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(path[parseInt(k)-1]) ;
            if ( typeof path[parseInt(k)+1] != 'undefined' ) nextLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(path[parseInt(k)+1]) ;

            var etat = 'lastLatLng='+lastLatLng + '<br />' +
                       'currentLatLng='+currentLatLng+'<br />' +
                       'nextLaLng='+nextLatLng+'<br />' ;

            if ( lastLatLng === null && nextLatLng !== null )
            {
              for ( var i = 0 ; i <= 180 ; i += 10 )
              {
                var heading = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(currentLatLng,nextLatLng)) + 90 + i ;
                addPoint(heading,currentLatLng,false) ;
              }
            }

            if ( lastLatLng !== null )
            {
              headingRight = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(currentLatLng,lastLatLng)) - 90 ;
              addPoint(headingRight,currentLatLng) ;
            }

            if ( lastLatLng !== null && nextLatLng !== null )
            {
                cas = 'intermediaires' ;
                var headingBefore = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(currentLatLng,lastLatLng) ;
                var headingAfter = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(currentLatLng,nextLatLng) ;
                headingBefore += 360 ; headingBefore = headingBefore % 360 ;
                headingAfter += 360 ; headingAfter = headingAfter % 360 ;
                
                headingRight = parseFloat( ( headingBefore + headingAfter ) / 2 ) ;
                if ( headingAfter > headingBefore ) headingRight += 180 ;
                headingRight += 360 ;
                
                headingRight = headingRight % 360 ;

                addPoint(headingRight,currentLatLng) ;
            }

            if ( nextLatLng !== null )
            {
              headingRight = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(currentLatLng,nextLatLng)) + 90 ;
              addPoint(headingRight,currentLatLng) ;
            }

            if ( lastLatLng !== null && nextLatLng === null )
            {
              for ( var i = 0 ; i <= 180 ; i += 10 )
              {
                var heading = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(currentLatLng,lastLatLng)) - 90 - i ;
                addPoint(heading,currentLatLng,false) ;
              }
            }

            
            if ( debug )
            {
              var content = etat+'<hr />'+
                'k='+k+'<br />'+
                'cas='+cas+'<br />'+
                'currentLatLng='+currentLatLng+'<br />'+
                'path[k]='+path[k]['lat']+','+path[k]['lng']+' <br /> '+
                'headingBefore='+headingBefore+'<br />'+
                'headingAfter='+headingAfter+'<br />'+
                'headingRight='+headingRight+'<br />'+
                'headingLeft='+headingLeft+'<br />' ;
                /*
                'pointLeft='+pointLeft.lat()+','+pointLeft.lng()+'<br />'+
                'pointLeft='+pointRight.lat()+','+pointRight.lng() ;
                */

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: path[k],
                map: map,
                title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
              });
              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow() ;
              
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
                return function() {
                  closeInfos();
                  infowindow.setContent(content);
                  infowindow.open(map,marker);
                  
                  infos[0]=infowindow;
                  
                  };
              })(marker,content,infowindow));
            }
            
        }
        
        /*
        console.log(path) ;
        console.log(polyTop) ;
        console.log(polyBottom) ;
        */
        // At this point, polyTop and polyBottom should contain a pass parrallel as your initial path, but from widthInMeter/2 on left of the orig. path for polyFrom and  widthInMeter/2 on right for polyBottom.
        
       // It's a start, but if we want to draw a complex polygon, we need only one path of coordinates.
       // What we need to do know is "mix" the 2 pathes into one, reversing bottomPath so the path created will go from first element of polyTop, to last element of polyTop, then last element of polyBottom and finish on last element of polyBottom. It should result in a sort a huge polygon making a "tour" around your original path.
       
       new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: polyLeft,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#00FF00',
          strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity,
          strokeWeight: 2
        }).setMap(map) ;

       new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: polyRight,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#0000FF',
          strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity,
          strokeWeight: 2
        }).setMap(map) ;

        polyRight.reverse() ;
        var polys = polyLeft.concat(polyRight) ;
       
        var complexPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: polys,
            strokeOpacity: 0,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
        });
        complexPoly.setMap(map); 
        
        function closeInfos(){
         
           if(infos.length > 0){
         
              /* detach the info-window from the marker ... undocumented in the API docs */
              infos[0].set("marker", null);
         
              /* and close it */
              infos[0].close();
         
              /* blank the array */
              infos.length = 0;
           }
        }

        function addPoint(hRight,currentLatLng,both=true)
        {
          hLeft = hRight + 180 ;
          if ( hLeft > 360 ) hLeft -= 360 ;
          if ( hRight > 360 ) hRight -= 360 ;

          var pointRight = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(currentLatLng,widthInMeters/2,hRight) ;
          var pointLeft  = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(currentLatLng,widthInMeters/2,hLeft) ;

          if ( ! isNaN(pointLeft.lat()) && ! isNaN(pointRight.lat()) )
          {
              if ( both ) polyLeft.push({'lat':pointLeft.lat(),'lng':pointLeft.lng()}) ;
              polyRight.push({'lat':pointRight.lat(),'lng':pointRight.lng()}) ;    
          }
        }

    }) ;
```

```css
#map {

  width:400px ;
  height:200px ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
    <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the strokeweight doesn't have any connection to meters in width. If a user has a path width of 75 meters there is no way to convert that to a correct strokeweight or width. The polyline needs to be exactly the typed in width. This is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651293/draw-google-polyline-with-line-width-set-in-meters but the only answer is a javascript API not available on the Android or iOS Google SDK. Doing a pixel conversion sounds risky across different devices anyways.

Comment: Yes it's clearly unprecise with strokeWeight. I've edited my answer with a start of a solution creating a polygon around your path : could you take a look on it ?

Comment: That's a very good idea. I can draw parallel polylines and just make the width of the lines thin so that it doesn't affect it as much. Next, I will highlight the area between the lines. Thanks! I think I can make a large polygon to fill in the center. Ill close the bottom and top so that it is always showing one large polygon.

Comment: Made another edit with something working on snippet : i just have issues on last point and when original path turn too much :(

Comment: I see you concatenated the paths to make one. Can't seem to find a method that does that in the iOS Google Maps. I guess I just need to loop and copy each location entry from one to the other?

Comment: Well even in JS it's just a merge of 2 arrays. You only need to reverse the second one to make a "circle", then you'll have one path making a loop and usable for polygon.

Comment: I've updated another more precise attempt : it looks not that far from what you're looking... but still in JS. This was a question i already had, at that time i was trying to find every markers in the range of a polyline (places where to sleep in 5km range of a hiking trail). I was using circles drawn at every point on the path, it's good until you have a large distance between 2 points. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154254/google-map-multiple-overlay-no-cumulative-opacity

Comment: Thanks again. I made another post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334797/google-maps-path-encoding I'm have a little trouble merging the GMSMutablePaths together. I reversed the bottom side. Encoded them as strings and then merged the strings. And then put back into GMSMutablePath. My polygons keep shooting up to the north pole.

Answer (score 0):

check this, I faced the same issue and solved with this: 
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/373#issuecomment-318502509